# Spring roo field reference to referenced entity VIEW

Tags: spring-roo

I created entities Applications and Versions.
In the application view I can write application name and select previously created version. 
I used command field reference (focused on Applications) to do that:

```
field reference --type ~.Versions --fieldName version --cardinality
```

After that I would like to create third entity called Upgrade and here is the problem.
In the Upgrade view when I select previously created Application (app name and version) I see only application name, there is no version there.

My code:

```
project --topLevelPackage xyz.apss.tests
jpa setup --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY --provider HIBERNATE
entity jpa --class Applications
field string --fieldName appName
entity jpa --class Versions
field string --fieldName version
focus --class ~.Applications
field reference --type ~.Versions --fieldName version --cardinality  
entity jpa --class Upgrade
field reference --type ~.Applications --fieldName appName
web mvc setup
web mvc all --package ~.web
```

Sorry, no images, no reputation enough. :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a to [this explication about the version field on JPA](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/fields#Version_Field_). Looks like you have a field name conflict. Try to change `version` field to something like `versionNumber`.

Good luck!